# Is there any way to get Postgres to use proper ISO 8601 timestamps globally and automatically?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, iso8601

As far as I can tell, Postgres 10.12 is not using proper ISO 8601 timestamps for my `timestamptz` columns: `2021-03-21 00:23:18.587565`

Per ISO 8601:

> A single point in time can be represented by concatenating a complete date expression, the letter "T" as a delimiter, and a valid time expression. For example, "2007-04-05T14:30". In ISO 8601:2004 it was permitted to omit the "T" character by mutual agreement as in "200704051430", but this provision was removed in ISO 8601-1:2019. Separating date and time parts with other characters such as space is not allowed in ISO 8601, but allowed in its profile RFC 3339. <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)</sup>

Is there any way I can configure this globally, so I get timestamps in the `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.xxxZ` format? My current workaround is querying like this every time I want a timestamp:

```sql
SELECT to_json(created_at) #>> '{}' AS created_at FROM items
```

This is quite tedious, and a global option would be much preferred.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/sql-set.html) will help?

Comment: @JeffHolt I came across `SET DATESTYLE` but I don't see any way to set the format the way I want it.

Comment: @JeffHolt: Please link to the current version, not the Dinosaur-version: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens Sorry, I should mention I'm on Postgres 10.12. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in PostgreSQL to configure the string representation of timestamps beyond the `datestyle` parameter, which offers only a few fixed alternatives.

The best advice I can give you to use `to_char` with an appropriate format string.